# Error while starting Meteor App: illegal operation on a directory, unlink ".../dev_bundle"

Tags: meteor

I get this Error when trying to start my application on my server with the command:

```
meteor
```

error:

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, unlink '/home/.../.../myapp/.meteor                   /local/dev_bundle'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.unlinkSync (fs.js:932:18)
    at exports.makeLink (/tools/cli/dev-bundle-links.js:20:8)
    at [object Object].ensureDevBundleLink (/tools/project-context.js:1416:7)
    at [object Object]._readFile (/tools/project-context.js:1350:10)
    at new exports.ReleaseFile (/tools/project-context.js:1300:8)
    at /tools/cli/main.js:825:22
```

My app is running fine on my dev. win. machine.

I have no idea what is causing the error, please help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got it working by manually removing all directories and links where the name started with "dev_bundle" inside the "/.meteor/local" directory.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Also update meteor to the latest version using `meteor update` and then follow @henk's solution.
This worked for me.